MySQL8 - mysqld_'--no-monitor' option not working
After installing and benchmarking MySQL8 version (8.0.33-commercial) on a windows server, I've tried to disable second process mysqld (automatically launched as monitoring process).
So installing an instance mysql8 as daemon without two processes is not possible ?
Please I need help ..
I've tried disabling it with --no-monitor in my command :
mysqld.exe -install MySQL8_3316 --defaults-file="[MYSQL_SERVER8_PATH]\DATAS\my.ini" --no-monitor=ON
--install is the same !
(Source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_no-monitor)
2 problems :

first : an error appeared with :


Failed to set datadir to [MYSQL_SERVER8_PATH]\data and **Can't create test file [MYSQL_SERVER8_PATH]\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test and **


second : since data was created manually to bypass 1st issue, with defaut mysql db/tables :


2024-09-05T12:50:53.576226Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000069] [Server] [MYSQL_SERVER8_PATH]\bin\mysqld.exe: unknown option '-i'.

